# findcontrold from Sender object which is inside a master page - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

Initially had individual aspx pages and all worked fine, then i had to implement it into master pages.
This code was done years ago and now needed conversion to html5.

What working is when i mention control names explicitly

```
'find contentplaceholder

 Dim mpContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
        mpContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("HomePlaceholder"), ContentPlaceHolder)
'find the control
        AnnounceSnippet = DirectCast(mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("AnnounceSnippet"), Control.ContentSnippet)
```

Before the implementation of master template the following was working fine

```
#Region "View Particular Day"
   Public Sub lbtDayView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim dtmSelectedDate As DateTime = DirectCast(Page.FindControl(DirectCast(sender, Calendar).ClientID), Calendar).SelectedDate()
```

But afterwards as it is giving null pointer exception i tried to used the master content holder

```
 Dim dtmSelectedDate As DateTime = DirectCast(mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl(DirectCast(sender, Calendar).ClientID), Calendar).SelectedDate()
```

still no clue.

Can anyone kindly help>

here is my aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HomePlaceholder">
......
<uc1:contentsnippet id="AnnounceSnippet" runat="server"></uc1:contentsnippet>
.....
<asp:calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:calendar>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

ah found it!!!.

When i did a debug on it, it returned "HomePlaceholder_Calendar1" as clientID as opposed to just "Calendar1" , so did a string replace, i know its not the proper way, but it is the only way i have got now to work it out.